# MySQL:how to export data from mysql to a txt?

Tags: mysql

i want to export data from mysql to a txt.

i use

*select * from users2 into outfile 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\1.txt'*

but there is an error:

*ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement*

i try to solve with:
show variables like '%secure%';
the result is that:

+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                          |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| require_secure_transport | OFF                                            |
| secure_auth              | ON                                             |
| secure_file_priv         | C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\ |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------+

the path is that i use in the above.
so i don`t know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go through the MySQL Documentation regarding this, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv):

Documentation quotes the following points:

> `secure_file_priv` may be set as follows:
>
> - If empty, the variable has no effect. This is not a secure setting.
> - If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export operations to work only with files in that directory. The directory must exist; the server will not create it.
> - If set to `NULL`, the server disables import and export operations. This value is permitted as of `MySQL` 5.7.6.

Based on the above, you have to explicitly specify this in your `my.cnf` as the following:

- A `""` value can be set with `secure_file_priv=""`
- A `NULL` value can be set with `secure_file_priv=NULL`
- A specific folder value can be with `secure_file_priv=My_Specific_Output_Folder`

By this, you might want to decide upon the options available and make the necessary change in your `my.cnf` file and RESTART your MySQL Server service. Once the service is restarted, then you should be able to export data from your query.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i think my condition belongs to the third one. the path is "C：\ ProgramData \ MySQL \ MySQL Server 5.7 \ Uploads \ ". i use this path but also failed.